# Using flatMap and Math.max to get a certain field's highest value from obj

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am currently working with an object and trying to extract the highest value of `duration` field. I am trying to use both `flatMap` and `Math.max` to achieve this but so far I am getting a `-Infinity` result. I am also calling this `flatMap` twice which is likely not right :/. What would be the right  approach to get the highest value of `duration`?

```
const users = [{
        name: 'User1',
        configuration: [{
                email: 'test1@email.com',
                duration: 60,
                active: true
            },
            {
                email: 'test2@email.com',
                duration: 180,
                active: false
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'User2',
        configuration: [{
                email: 'test3@email.com',
                duration: 120,
                active: true
            },
            {
                email: 'test4@email.com',
                duration: 30,
                active: true
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'User3',
        configuration: [{
                email: 'test5@email.com',
                duration: 300,
                active: true
            },
            {
                email: 'test6@email.com',
                duration: 10,
                active: true
            }
        ],
    },
];
```

Code:

```
const x = users.flatMap(user => user.configuration);
const y = x.flatMap(user => user.duration);
const highestvalue = Math.max(...Object.values(y).flat().flatMap(Object.values));
console.log(highestvalue);
```

Current Result:

```
-Infinity
```

Desired Result:

```
300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, your `y` array contains the list of `destination` values. You can use `Math.max(...y)` to get the max number from that array. While you're calling `.flatMap()` twice, you only need to call it once on your original `users` array to flatten the objects within your `configuration` arrays into one resulting array. Once you have these objects flattened you don't need to call it again when you map `x` and instead can use just `.map()`:

```js
const users = [{ name: 'User1', configuration: [{ email: 'test1@email.com', duration: 60, active: true }, { email: 'test2@email.com', duration: 180, active: false } ], }, { name: 'User2', configuration: [{ email: 'test3@email.com', duration: 120, active: true }, { email: 'test4@email.com', duration: 30, active: true } ], }, { name: 'User3', configuration: [{ email: 'test5@email.com', duration: 300, active: true }, { email: 'test6@email.com', duration: 10, active: true } ], }, ];

const x = users.flatMap(user => user.configuration);
const y = x.map(user => user.duration);
console.log(Math.max(...y));
```

You can also simplify by removing the intermediate variables by mapping each object which each `configuration` array to its duration, and which then gets flattened into one resulting array due to the outer `.flatMap()`:

```js
const users = [{ name: 'User1', configuration: [{ email: 'test1@email.com', duration: 60, active: true }, { email: 'test2@email.com', duration: 180, active: false } ], }, { name: 'User2', configuration: [{ email: 'test3@email.com', duration: 120, active: true }, { email: 'test4@email.com', duration: 30, active: true } ], }, { name: 'User3', configuration: [{ email: 'test5@email.com', duration: 300, active: true }, { email: 'test6@email.com', duration: 10, active: true } ], }, ];

const highest = Math.max(...users.flatMap(
  user => user.configuration.map(({duration}) => duration)
));

console.log(highest);
```

---

Note, as [@Chris_F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897778/chris-f) pointed out, if you expect your array to be large or are unsure of the size of your array, then you may potentially run into the max argument limitation when trying to spread your array elements into `Math.max()`. In this case, you can use a loop to find the max value (rather than spreading the arrary elements), below I've used `.reduce()`:

```js
const max = arr => arr.reduce((m, c) => Math.max(m, c), -Infinity);

const users = [{ name: 'User1', configuration: [{ email: 'test1@email.com', duration: 60, active: true }, { email: 'test2@email.com', duration: 180, active: false } ], }, { name: 'User2', configuration: [{ email: 'test3@email.com', duration: 120, active: true }, { email: 'test4@email.com', duration: 30, active: true } ], }, { name: 'User3', configuration: [{ email: 'test5@email.com', duration: 300, active: true }, { email: 'test6@email.com', duration: 10, active: true } ], }, ];

const highest = max(users.flatMap(
  user => user.configuration.map(({duration}) => duration)
));

console.log(highest);
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use array spreading with Math.max to find the largest value in an array. This may work with small array. but in my browser this generates a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" with an array length over ~128,000. Some engines may have lower maximums.

Comment: @Chris_F good point - if OPs array is expected to be large, then a loop over the array to find the max is a better option to avoid passing `Math.max()` too many arguments

Comment: @Chris_F - You are right! It works fine now but the array could be expected to grow. I ended up looping over the array to find the max.